# AG GRID - Get Column Value

Tags: javascript, ag-grid

I render the table with AG-GRID, and I need to get at the last column of each row to 'data.Id' row value plus 'uu' row value into onClick function, to create link, I try some things but nothing work.
I have 2 grids MainGrid and MainViewGrid (main grid row has a one or more mainview grid values), and render link from 2 parameters in mainview grid is problem

```
columnDefs: [
                {
                    headerName: 'ID',
                    maxWidth: 100,
                    valueGetter: 'node.id',
                    cellRenderer: 'loadingRenderer',
                    suppressMenu: true,
                    hide: true,
                },
                {
                    field: 'cv',
                    headerName: 'cv',
                    minWidth: 200,
                },
                {
                    field: 'ss',
                    headerName: 'ss',
                    minWidth: 100,
                },
                {
                    field: 'zz',
                    headerName: 'zz',
                    minWidth: 150,
                },
                {
                    field: 'uu',
                    headerName: 'uu',
                    minWidth: 100,
                },
                {
                    field: 'dd',
                    headerName: 'dd',
                    minWidth: 150,
                },
                {
                    field: 'cc',
                    headerName: 'cc',
                    maxWidth: 85,
                    cellRenderer: 'btnCellRenderer',
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        buttonText: 'Detail',
                        clicked: function (field) {
                  
                              window.location.href = '@(Url.Action("Detail", "cc"))/' + field + '/' + node.id + uu
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
```

Could you please help me ?

**Update:**

I got undefined for data parameter, not sure if its good fix, check data param if its null

```
              {
                    field: 'cc',
                    headerName: 'cc',
                    maxWidth: 85,
                    cellRenderer: ({ data, buttonText, basePath }) => {                       
                        if (data == null) {
                            return null;
                        }
                        return "<a href='" + basePath + "/" + data.cc+ "/" + data.uu + "'>" + buttonText + "</a>";
                    },
                    cellRendererParams: {
                        buttonText: "Detail",
                        basePath: '@(Url.Action("Detail", "cc"))/'
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When grid invokes your `btnCellRenderer` it passes parameters (cell value, row data, grid API, column API, context object) plus extra params you provide in column definition `cellRendererParams`.
Basically, you can get access to anything you may need within your renderer.

Here is how your last column may be configured:

```
{
  field: "cc",
  headerName: "cc",
  maxWidth: 85,
  cellRenderer: ({ data, node, buttonText, basePath }) => {
    return <a href={`${basePath}field/${node.id + data.uu}`}>{buttonText}</a>;
  },
  cellRendererParams: {
    buttonText: "Detail",
    basePath: '@(Url.Action("Detail", "cc"))/'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @mashi, thank you for your help. I got the message: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')`, first time I got Udenfined and second time I got all data via `console.log(data);`

Comment: any suggestion please?

Comment: do you have any row grouping or tree data in your grid?

Comment: no it is only a simple rest response array, where I use  `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
                initializeMainGrid();
                initializeMainVersionGrid();
            });`, I have main grid, and after render data in first, after click on any row in Main Grid was start rendering MainVersionGrid (second ajax/rest API request)